# unicorn/rails server errors in production, but doesn't write to log or stderr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Where is my stack trace?

I have a small Rails 3.2 app that I am trying to get running under unicorn proxied to an Apache vhost on a Linode server. In development mode locally, and on the linode, it works as expected. But as soon as I throw the `-E production` switch, I get the error in the browser that "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

So, of course I try to look in the logs to see what the issue is. But there is NOTHING in the app `log` dir. Nor is there any useful info in `/var/log/apache2`.

So, I tried to reduce the situation to its essentials, and just running and accessing `unicorn_rails` directly gives the same exact problem. The only output should be to stdout/stderr, and nothing is shown there either.

```
$ bundle exec unicorn -E production -p 9092   
I, [2012-03-10T15:02:50.208750 #2891]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:9092 fd=7
I, [2012-03-10T15:02:50.211113 #2891]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2012-03-10T15:02:50.224912 #2891]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2012-03-10T15:02:50.225570 #2908]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=2908
I, [2012-03-10T15:02:50.225900 #2908]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-03-10T15:03:00.725142 #2908]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
cache: [GET /] miss
cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
```

As I said, if I change to development mode then it works normally. It also doesn't matter whether I run the above as root or as a normal user.

I am using RVM so that could be an issue, but unicorn does run in development - and all the required gems are installed.

With the `-d` debug flag for unicorn, I get lots of warnings and exceptions related to certain gems, in either production or development mode. I'm not seeing anything interesting in the debug output, but can post that if it helps.

Comment: I ran the site in production under webrick, and it wrote to `logs/production.log` (the error had to do with sprockets pre-compiling assets, no suprise). But the question remains, because running under unicorn in production I am still getting no exceptions in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it - BUG IN RAILS :P

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277

fixed by updating to 3.2.2